# LLenar un text input cuando cambie de opcion un select

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

tengo una duda acerca de como llenar un text input cuando cambio de opcion en un select, esto lo hago por que quiero que cuando seleccione el nombre del paciente se llene un input con su numero de telefono, estoy trabajando con codeiniter, bootstrap modals y AJAX, he probado con el evento change del select pero no me llena le imput con la opcion del select, les muestro como esta mi codigo:

select (bootstrap selecpicker):

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
     <label>Paciente</label>
     <select class="form-control dropup show-tick" data-live-search="true" id="slc_cliente" style="width: 100%;" title="Selecciona un Paciente" data-width="100%" data-size="3" data-header="Buscar Paciente" data-style="btn-light">
     </select>
</div>
```

el input donde quiero que se muestre el telefono:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
    <label>Telefono</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txttelefono" disabled>
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="fa fa-phone"></span>
            </span>
     </div>
</div>
```

el AJAX de donte obtengo toda la informacion de los pacientes (id, nombre, apellidos y telefono):

```
$.post(baseurl + "cCalendar/getClientes",
function (data) {
    var clientes = JSON.parse(data);
    $.each(clientes, function (i, item) {
        $('#slc_cliente').append('<option data-icon="fa fa-user" value="' + item.id_cliente + '">' + item.cliente + '</option>');
    });
});
```

alguna idea de como hacer? soy super novato con Jquery y Javascript...
es la mejor manera de hacerlo o sugieren alguna otra?

saludos y gracias por su ayuda de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

encontre una solucion un poco ortodoxa pero me funciona asi que la dejo aqui, asi como obtenia los datos de los clientes (id, nombres, apellidos, etc), tambien hice una funcion en el controlador y en el modelo para obtener solo el tenefono, lo deje asi al final, por si para alguien es de ayuda:

script en la view.php:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slc_cliente').change(function() {
        IdTEL();
        InfoTEL(TelefonoCliente);
    });
});

function IdTEL() {
    TelefonoCliente = {
        idc: $("#slc_cliente").val()
    };
}

function InfoTEL(TelefonoCliente) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>cCalendar/getTelefonos',
        data: TelefonoCliente,
        success: function(data) {
            var clientes = JSON.parse(data);
            $.each(clientes, function(i, item) {
                $('#txttelefono').val(item.telefono);
            });
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('Hay un Error!!!');
        }
    });
}
```

controlador.php:

```
public function getTelefonos()
{
    $idc = $this->input->post('idc');

    $r = $this->Mcalendar->getTelefonos($idc);

    echo json_encode($r);
}
```

modelo.php:

```
public function getTelefonos($idc)
{
    $this->db->select(c.id_cliente, c.telefono);
    $this->db->from('t_clientes c');
    $this->db->where('c.id_cliente', $idc);

    $param = $this->db->get();
    return $param->result();
}
```

si existe una mejor manera, estoy abierto a sugerencias, pero de esta manera funciona a la perfeccion, saludos y felices fiestas.